# Serving images from a Raspberry Pi camera over HTTP

Tags: python, image, http, web-services, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi with a [camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/python/README.md) that I control with Python.

I created a web server with [web.py](http://webpy.org/) that allows me to make HTTP requests to the PI to retrieve an image. There are two optional parameters to specify the width and height of the image. The code looks like this (`import`s omitted):

```
urls = (
    '/capture', 'Capture'
)

# start with default values for resolution
width = 1024
height = 768

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()

class Capture:
    def GET(self):
        input = web.input(w="0", h="0")                 # reading user input of resolution values for 

        input.w = int(input.w)                          # to integer
        input.h = int(input.h)

        if input.w == 0:
            input.w = width                             # no width given, use saved one
        else:
            input.w = max(0,min(2592, input.w))         # clamp to range of valid values

        if input.h == 0:
            input.h = height                            # no height given, use saved one
        else:
            input.h = max(0,min(1944, input.h))         # clamp to range of valid values

        camera = picamera.PiCamera()                    # camera
        camera.resolution = (input.w, input.h)
        camera.capture('picture.jpg')                   # capture image to file
        camera.close()

        web.header('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
        return open('picture.jpg',"rb").read()          # read image from file and respond
```

I understand that the code handling the width and height is not very elegant and could be shorter.

To get an image, I can enter `http://<PI IP address>/capture` in a browser. The problem is that it takes quite a while (1311ms): waiting 1264ms and receiving 47ms.

The results are obviously the same on different browsers because this is a server-side issue.

**How can I get the image more quickly?**

I think saving to an image file first and reopening that to get the return value is redundant (and possibly slow), but I don't know how to make the `capture()` function return the value directly (so that I could return it to the client directly). I do not necessarily need jpeg format.

Comment: possible hints: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24259

Comment: Besides the hint given by user3802077, I would like to ask the following question: what have *you* done to determine the bottleneck. Look into profiling the code. Add logging of timestamps at various points to see which sequence takes the longest. For instance, how long does `input.w = int(input.w)` take? How long does `camera.capture('picture.jpeg')` take? Finding it out by hand teaches you more than a code review would give you.

Comment: It take a long time to save the image to the hard drive (which might be an SD card in this case). Try using variables instead, but I am also trying to figure out how.